# $toInt vs $convert with mongo (pymongo), is one approach preferable vs the other

Tags: mongodb, type-conversion, pymongo

Using Python's `pymongo` library, the following accomplish the same task in roughly the same amount of time:

```
my_collection.update_many(
  {}, 
  [{'$set': {'ptsScored': {'$toInt': '$ptsScored'}}}]
)

my_collection.update_many(
  {}, 
  [{ '$set': { 'ptsScored': { '$convert': { 'input': "$ptsScored", 'to': 16 } } }}]
)
```

Both successfully turn the `ptsScored` field from string to int. Types from [this link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/type/#available-types). Given equal performance, is there any reason to use 1 approach over the other? Is 1 of `$toInt` or `$convert` newer than the other? Or is it 100% preference on which to use at this point and moving forward?

Comment: There is no difference in the two operator functionality; `$toInt` is a syntactic sugar. Both operators were introduced with MongoDB v4.0.

Comment: makes sense, thanks. Yes `$toInt` feels a bit cleaner and a bit easier to use

Comment: They both perform the same function, but $convert allows you to specify how to deal with errors, non-numeric strings, etc, where $toInt will just fail if it encounters anything unexpected.